# IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo not called on WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to enable DPI support per the instructions Microsoft gives [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622670.aspx). I'm using the WPF `WebBrowser` control like this:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="BrowserPane"
                Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/HTML/index.html"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                LoadCompleted="BrowserPane_LoadCompleted"/>
</Grid>
```

My code behind implements `IDocHostUIHandler` like this:

```
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwID, [In] Native.POINT pt, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pcmdtReserved, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pdispReserved)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo([In, Out] Native.DOCHOSTUIINFO info)
    {
        info.dwFlags = (uint)Native.DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DPI_AWARE;
        info.dwDoubleClick = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowUI([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwID, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object activeObject, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object commandTarget, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object frame, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object doc)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.HideUI()
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.UpdateUI()
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.EnableModeless([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fEnable)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.OnDocWindowActivate([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fActivate)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.OnFrameWindowActivate([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fActivate)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ResizeBorder([In] Native.COMRECT rect, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object doc, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fFrameWindow)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateAccelerator([In] ref MSG msg, [In] ref Guid group, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint nCmdID)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetOptionKeyPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] string[] pbstrKey, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dw)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetDropTarget([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pDropTarget, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface), Out] out object ppDropTarget)
    {
        ppDropTarget = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetExternal([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch), Out] out object ppDispatch)
    {
        ppDispatch = this.Browser.ObjectForScripting;
        return S_OK;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateUrl([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwTranslate, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strURLIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), Out] out string pstrURLOut)
    {
        pstrURLOut = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.FilterDataObject([In] IDataObject pDO, [Out] out IDataObject ppDORet)
    {
        ppDORet = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
```

And I set the handler in the `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted` event like this:

```
    var doc = this.Browser.Document as Native.ICustomDoc;
    if (doc != null)
        doc.SetUIHandler(this);
```

Some of the methods on `IDocHostUIHandler` are getting called. Such as `ShowContextMenu` which is successfully disabling the context menu. But `GetHostInfo` is never called. Am I setting the UI handler too late?

EDIT: It's been observed that this code works on some Win10 machines, but not MY Win10 machine. Is there something else on my machine that needs to be configured for this to work?